# WCF Trace log won't show spaces in messages?

Tags: xml, wcf, logging, wcf-rest, trace

I have a Restful WCF service running with Tracing enabled using `XmlWriterTraceListener`, it is working well with one slight issue:

If user posted data contains space (or spaces) it won't recorded by the tracing log (as I can't see it in the Microsoft Service Trace Viewer).

For example, if user posted data include the following field (4 spaces):

```
<ATextField>    </ATextField>
```

The object deserialized on the server side will have `ATextField='    '`.

However, when checking from the Microsoft Service Trace Viewer, I can only see the incoming message like below (no spaces):

```
<ATextField></ATextField>
```

Is this a configuration issue, or how can I make it logging/showing correct messages?